# Flash AOSP image on Pixel 3a

Tags: android, android-source

I managed to build AOSP codenamed `sargo`. I have a bunch of .img files now
How do I flash them on my device using `fastboot flash` after unlocking the bootloader.

List of images built, do I need to flash all of them?

- boot.img
- dtb.img
- dtbo.img
- persist.img
- product.img
- ramdisk-debug.img
- ramdisk-recovery.img
- ramdisk.img
- super_empty.img
- system_other.img
- system.img
- vbmeta.img

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [this](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/complete-guide-flashing-factory-images-android-using-fastboot-0175277/) guide for flashing these kind of images using `fastboot flash` command.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a vendor.img. Did you download the correct proprietary files and run the script? The proprietary files for sargo are [here](https://developers.google.com/android/drivers#sargo). Make sure you download the files that correspond with your build. You probably wouldn't be able to use the screen when the device booted without a vendor.img.